# Is my interpretation correct?Can I print binary representation for double, as eg:1?

Tags: c, binary, double

Write a program to print binary form of double? I reckoned that, **eg:1** representation is to be printed. Is it correct to print like that? Or should I print in **eg:2** format.

eg:

1. binary representation for **23.5** is  **0000000000000000000000000010111.1**
2. where IEEE754 format says real data stored in computer's memory as

   0 | 10000011 | 0111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

   sign | exponent | significand

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>

    main()
   {
   double decimal,decimal1,f;

   int nbits,num,i,j,a[32],b[50],n;

   printf("enter double:");

   scanf("%lf",&f);

   num=(int)f;//to get integral part of float

   /*finding binary equivalent of integral part and storing them in an array */

   nbits=sizeof(num)*8-1;

   j=nbits;

   for(i=0;i<=nbits;i++)
   {
    a[j]=(num>>i)&1;

    j--;

   }

   f=(f>0)?f:(-f);// to get absolute value if float is a negative number

   num=(num)>0?num:(-num);

   decimal=f-(double)num;

   decimal1=decimal;

   /*to get binary equivalent of decimal part*/

   for(i=0;decimal!=0;i++)
   {
   decimal=decimal*2;


   b[i]= (int)decimal;

   n=i;


   if(decimal==decimal1) //to stop recurrence of decimal points

   {


        break;


   }

   if(decimal>=1)

   {
       decimal=decimal-1;
   }
   ```

   }

   ```
   for(i=0;i<=31;i++)

   {

    printf("%d",a[i]);

   }
   ```

   printf(".");

   ```
   for(i=0;i<=n;i++)

   {
   printf("%d",b[i]);
   ```

   }

   ```
   printf("\n");
   ```

   }

In the above code to stop recurrence, I have given **break** statement to break the loop. I have checked the values **decimal1** and **decimal** for each iteration. Even if **decimal1=decimal**, the loop is not break. But loop is getting terminated when n=46. I am unable understand what is happening there. Please help me to rectify.

And I want to know whether my code is correct to print binary equivalent of double.

I need to get output in the following form

```
1st execution:
enter double:23.5
0000000000000000000000000010111.1

2nd execution:
enter double:23.4
0000000000000000000000000010111.0110
```

In second execution, I have entered 23.4. Binary equivalent of  **0.4** is  recurrence of 0110. I have used break statement to stop recurrence. So as per my analysis of my code, 2nd execution output should be like above format.But I am getting the below output for **23.4**

```
enter double:23.4
0000000000000000000000000010111.01100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

I am unable to understand what makes the **2nd for loop** termination after printing 47 bits.

Comment: Not even close. First, you cast to `int`. What about all those doubles outside the range of int?  I'm not sure what you think this is supposed to do.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "binary format of double"? Are you trying to print the internal format that the number is stored in, or print the number as a fractional decimal? (Completely different.)

Comment: print the number as a fractional decimal

Comment: Any particular reason not to use printf with one of the floating point format specifiers, such as %g?

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually displays the correct result. `0.5=1/2` so 23.5 has only one "two-cimal". It is not the case of 0.4, which has an infinite number of "two-cimal".

[image: formula]

With `printf()`, you may print an interger using its hexadecimal (hexa=16) representation with flag `%x` and a double using its hexadecimal floating point representation with `%a`. Use `%.9a` to display 9 "16-cimals".

A piece of code to test it :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a=23.5;
    int ai=(int)a;
    double b=a-ai;
    printf("a : %.9a ai : %x b=a-ai : %.15a == %.20g\n",a,ai,b,b);

    a=23.4;
    ai=(int)a;
    b=a-ai;
    printf("a : %.9a ai : %x b=a-ai : %.15a == %.20g\n",a,ai,b,b);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
a : 0x1.780000000p+4 ai : 17 b=a-ai : 0x1.000000000000000p-1 == 0.5
a : 0x1.766666666p+4 ai : 17 b=a-ai : 0x1.999999999998000p-2 == 0.39999999999999857891
```

Notice the 8 at the end : the recursive representation is missed by the 8 and all the zeros... And the for loop will not break until `decimal==0`. The total number of digit that are printed is 47+5=52, that is the size of [IEE754's `double` mantissa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).